# SSL: change autogenerated css

Tags: css, ssl, fonts

My site is using a font which is autogenerated in a `css` file. The problem is that the font's link is generated with `http` protocol so I receive this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://bluepharmacy.gr/index.php' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font
>   'http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensanscondensed/v7/gk5FxslNkTTHtojXrkp-xLF0I8LnmRdLRTOvKd-OXMQ.woff'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The autogenerated file is :

> / public_html / var / cache / misc / statics / design / themes /
>   basic_clone / css /
>   standalone.544cdba9ccf1ee5ba34279907d5924d41538391453.css

And it begins with these lines:

> /* ATTENTION! Please do not modify this file, it's auto-generated and
>   all your changes will be lost. The complete list of files it's
>   generated from: design/themes/basic_clone/css/reset.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/grid.less
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/lib/ui/jqueryui.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/base.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/glyphs.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/print.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/dropdown.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/scheme.less
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/gdpr/styles.less
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/social_buttons/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/news_and_emails/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/news_and_emails/scheme.less
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/hw_cookie_law/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/gift_certificates/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/gift_certificates/scheme.less
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/store_locator/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/bestsellers/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/form_builder/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/banners/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/discussion/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/discussion/scheme.less
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/wishlist/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/wishlist/scheme.less
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/hybrid_auth/colorbox.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/twigmo/styles.css
>   design/themes/basic_clone/css/addons/my_changes/styles.css
>   */

I searched in all the mentioned files and couldn't find the :

```
http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensanscondensed/v7/gk5FxslNkTTHtojXrkp-xLF0I8LnmRdLRTOvKd-OXMQ.woff
```

To change it to `https://*` .

And if I change it in css it will be generated again and will overwrite it again using `http://`

Comment: The css mostly is coded in directory paths. When going to the the woff file, this is loaded by HTTP protocol. Try changing the path of the http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensanscondensed/v7/gk5FxslNkTTHtojXrkp-xLF0I8LnmRdLRTOvKd-OXMQ.woff to https

Comment: @Jayruben the problem is that I cant find where to change it ...

Comment: find your page's HTML, or the thing that makes the page's HTML (like a template), and you'll likely find the google font include.

Comment: After checking the URL again, i think you have fixed this?

Comment: @Jayruben yes I used ssh command to find where exactly was this line and changed it and worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used ssh command to search the whole directory and located the file and the line where the font was loaded and changed it to https and now is ok.

Command:

```
find . -name "*.*" -exec grep -Hn "your search term here" {} \;
```